# How to realize this instruction and write variable in program?

Tags: assembly

I have a multifunction instruction - , dreg = DM(Ik,Mn). I know that this instruction performs an arithmetic operation and reads a value into a data register using indirect addressing. However, I don't fully understand how to implement this in the code and how to write a certain variable to I1, M1 in the ADSP-218x DSP assembler. Thank you in advance.

I have reviewed the literature, but I have not tried to write even a simple program because I am not sure how to write this instruction